# Pointers and arrays in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I understand the concept of pointers and arrays in C. My problem is the syntax of them. What is this:

```
char* var;
char var*;
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your premise is wrong. The first is the pointer type and the second is well... nothing, it is not valid C++ (neither is C for that matter).
Static arrays are more like this:

```
char var[15];
```

Dynamic arrays are on the other hand usually done with [vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/).

The confusion between arrays and pointers is a legacy from the C programming language, where `*(a+n)` and `a[n]` mean the same thing, so we can use the `a[n]` even if `a` is a pointer, not an array. This is not very idiomatic in C++ though.

Answer (score 7):

`char* var;` declares `var` to be a "pointer to `char`". `char var*;` is not a valid declaration.

An array would be declared something like: `char var[10];`.

Comment: Or something like: `std::array<char, 10> var;`

Comment: @chris that's not an array, that's an `std::array`. But yeah, I'd recommend that.

Comment: @classdaknok_t, it's the ideal static array to be using if you have the resources available to do so.

Comment: @classdaknok_t of course it's an array. Just not a C-style array, but this question is about C++.

Comment: @chris it's really not an array though, it just really acts like one. It's a class.

Comment: @SethCarnegie, of course, but the whole purpose of it is to replace the use of an array with a better alternative. We say `std::string` objects are strings, but strings in the base sense are still C-style character arrays. Hopefully `std::array` will take over in the same way one day.

Answer (score 3):

This is a pointer:

`char* var;`

This is syntactically incorrect, and will not compile:

```
char var*;
```

Arrays and pointers in C++ *are not the same thing*, but the syntax might make it seem like they are.  You can declare an array in C++ like this:

```
char ary[] = {'a','b','c'};
```

...and this is valid -- there will be an array created with 3 elements.

You can also create a function which takes a *pointer*:

```
void foo(char* bar)
{
// ...
}
```

...and pass it `ary`:

```
foo(ary);
```

...and it will compile and run fine.  This might lead you to believe that pointers and arrays are the same thing; but they aren't.  `bar` in `foo` above isn't an array -- it's a pointer that points to the first element of the array.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that in the call `foo(ary);`, `ary` decays into the needed pointer.